# creating table rows dynamically with AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following app using angular js that's im using to learn it with.  I have a table of rows and I want to dynamically add new rows into the table.  When I click the add button a new row is created, for some reason on occasions the position is incorrect.  Maybe the internal counter for the row is getting messed up but I can't see how or why this is happening..?

**Steps to recreate:**

1. Click the first 'add' button - notice the new row immediately below it.
2. Click the second 'add' button - notice the new row immediately below it.
3. Click the third 'add' button - notice the position is not as expected(?)

**I have a plunker available here**

https://plnkr.co/edit/WA2K8TNuEE6blNB6zBvZ?p=preview

Can anyone see why this happens?  The code that creates the new row is shown below

**Row creation code**

```
$scope.addRow = function(row) {
    var guid = new Date().getMilliseconds();
    var rowDate = row.date;

    var rowToAdd = {
        id: guid, 
        date: new Date(rowDate.getFullYear(), rowDate.getMonth(), rowDate.getUTCDay())
    };

     $scope.rows.splice(row.id, 0, rowToAdd);  
};
```

Any help much appreciated?

Thanks,

P.s if you reverse clicking the 'add' buttons, i.e. you click the third, second then the first 'add' button it works as expected - can't see why this makes a difference - I can guess it's a cursor problem but not sure why..

p.p.s the guid was to get around the angular problem with having duplicate keys restriction within an ng-repeat

Comment: First: your date formatting throws errors (`Error: [ngModel:nonassign] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/ngModel/nonassign?p0=r.date%20%7CNaNate%3A%20'EEEE'&p1=%3Cinput%20type%3D%22text%22%20ng-model%3D%22r.date%20%7C%date%3A%20'EEEE'%22%20style%3D%22width%3A%20100px%22%20class%3D%22ng-pristine%20ng-untouched%20ng-valid%22%3E`). Second, you could use `track by $index` instead of the guid: https://plnkr.co/edit/xq90WZNNlQJ5GFJRXEJb?p=preview

Comment: you don't need to add a random `id` value in order to handle duplicate keys, that's what `track by $index` on the `ng-repeat` is for.  also, since that `row.id` is a completely random value, you can't use it as the index to locate the insertion point in `splice`.

Comment: in the case of your `3` item in the list, if your item has 3 rows (`1, 2, 3`) and you click `3`, your new row will be inserted behind `3`, resulting in `1, 2, 3, random`).  however, if you click `1`, you get (`1, random, 2, 3`).  now, click `3`, and you expect it to be the last item ,but it will really be the "fourth" item, giving you (`1, random, 2, random, 3`).  you only notice it when you add `1` and `2` first, because of the values you are printing on screen (in that case, you get (`1, random, random, random, 2, 3`)).  Try printing the `row.id` on screen to see the real order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are using the `splice()` function wrong. If I understand your problem (I am not sure I do), you need to find the position of the current row, the clicked one, and based on that position insert the new row.

Here's my take on it: https://plnkr.co/edit/xq90WZNNlQJ5GFJRXEJb?p=preview - it still suffers from the problem that clicking on a later day will insert duplicate days, eg. clicking on "Thursday" will insert another "Wednesday". But the positioning is solid.

```
var index = $scope.rows.indexOf(row);

$scope.rows.splice(index, 0, rowToAdd);
```

Comment: it works looking at it..  What ever 'add' button I click it renders a new row immediately below the current row - this is what I wanted

Answer (score 2):

try to use $index to define the insert point:

at html:

```
<button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="addRow(r, $index)">add</button>
```

at js:

```
$scope.addRow = function(row, idx) {
    ...
    $scope.rows.splice(idx, 0, rowToAdd);
```

see the plunker: [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/hA9V89J3ee8ozwg8rWuF?p=preview)

Comment: while this *might* work, using `$index` for this purpose is error prone as well, since `$index` doesn't represent the array index of the item but the position of the item in `ng-repeat`, meaning that filtering and sorting can cause `$index` to be a value different than expected.

Comment: If there was a filter, the position of insert will be indifferent, and the parameter idx could be 0 allways. But originally the problem is the wrong point of insertion. But yes, you're correct.